# How to customize resolution of depth and rgb frame on Kinect sdk 1.8 c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, kinect-sdk

I'm new to kinect program as I know there are already provided resolution such as 640x320 for both rgb color and depth frame in ColorImageFormat and DepthImageFormat.
I would like to know is it possible to customize own resolution such as 120 x 120 ask I dont need very high resolution such as 640x320.

Thanks

Comment: Now I don't know much about Kinect, but to me this question seems better off on a Kinect forum or some such.

Answer (score 0):

You can always change the resolution at the user interface but as far as direct output from a Kinect v1 I think the only possible outputs are Resolution320x240fps30, Resolution640x480fps30 and Resolution80x60Fps30.